# Lightweight discussion board for joomla

Tags: joomla

I need a very lightweight discussion board for joomla 3.0. You should be able to enter a topic, name and message. I want people to be able to comment on the topics too. I do not want a full-fledged forum, just very basic.

The extensions I've found are all too advanced.

I'm thinking of two way to do this. Either by a custom form which submits an article in which comments are allowed, then i show them in a category listing. That would be great, but I'm not sure where to start to make that happen. I have some basic programming skills if needed.

The other way would be with a content creation extension I think? But since the ones I've looked at cost money I cant just test them and see if it works.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should look into this thing called "blog". ;)

Answer (score 0):

A forum is definitely too heavy for what you need. You might be better off looking at the [Blog](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog) category on the Joomla Extensions Directory. As you're using Joomla 3.0, you are a little more limited as to which extension you can use, however there are still a few:

Commercial:

1. [EasyBlog](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog/12630)
2. [RSBlog](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog/14679)

Non-Commerial:

1. [CjBlog](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog/22885)
2. [JUBlog](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/blog/19861)

As a second resourt, you could try using [Komento](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/articles-comments/20527)

Hope this helps